# Deleting a row in excel using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I've searched for the last few days on how to delete a row using vb.net in excel. I've found several methods, bt I couldn't get any to work. My code can be viewed below:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Scout As String
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer
    Dim xlrange As Excel.Range

    xlapp = New Excel.Application
    xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Computer Science\Program\Scouts1.xlsx")
    xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Worksheets("Member")
    xlrange = xlworksheet.UsedRange
    X = xlrange.Cells(1, 17).value

    Scout = CBMember.SelectedItem

    For i = 1 To X
        If Scout = xlrange.Cells(i, 2).value Then
            Y = xlrange.Cells(i, 1).value
            Y = Y + 1
        End If
    Next

    xlworksheet.DeleteRow(Y)

    xlworkbook.SaveAs("Scouts1")
    xlworkbook.Close()
    xlapp.Quit()

    Close()

End Sub
```

I've tried using xlworksheet.deleterow to delete the row but this doesn't seem to delete the row.

Comment: Have you verified that row represented by the variable "Y" is the one you expect it to be?  Add `xlApp.Visible=True` to your code and set a breakpoint on `xlworksheet.DeleteRow(Y)`.  Also, add `xlworksheet.Rows(Y).Select` before the delete statement.  When the debugger stops code execution, switch over to Excel and inspect the selected row.  Also, what Excel version are you using?  I have never seen the `DeleteRow` command before and it is not listed in current [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-object-excel).

Comment: So I've changed the code to xlworksheet.Rows (Y).delete. The code selects the right lines I want to delete and then deletes it. However, once it saves the data reappears.

Comment: `xlworkbook.SaveAs("Scouts1")` will save to Excel's default file path.  Are you looking at the correct file? Retrieve this path by adding `Dim appDefaultPath As String = xlApp.DefaultFilePath` and inspect the result.  Is the modified file stored in that folder?

Comment: That leads to a password file which shouldn't be password locked. I deleted it and replaced it with the same file which I could access but after running the program it became password locked again.

Comment: There has to be something you are not showing us.  The only way that saved workbook can have a password is if the original file is password protected or you explicitly set a password; neither of those two options are reflected in the code you have posted.  Assuming you chose to not show us a realistic workbook open statement, to clear the password add  `xlworkbook.Password=""` before saving it.